# Jimp - URIs are returned from the function but the images are not rendered in the <img>'s src

Tags: image, svelte, jimp

I am coding in Svelte and use *jimp* to blur the image before displaying. However, I successfully blur and return the images' URIs (logged and had the URIs displayed in the console), but the images are not render where i call the function in the `<img> src` .

Specifically:

I have a processImage function:

```
const processImage = async imgMeta => {

const buf = Buffer.from(imgMeta.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, ""), 'base64');

Jimp.read(buf, (err, image) => {
  if (err) throw err;
  else {
    image.blur(20)
    .getBase64(Jimp.AUTO, function (err, newImageURI) {          
      return newImageURI;
  })}})
```

And, i call it in the :

`<img src={processedImage} alt="preview" />`

But the image is not rendered. This is odds, as i expected it should work.

Comment: Change to current question!!!

The detailed codes of where the function is called:

`<div class="icon flex-row w-50 h-auto mv2">
        {#await processImage(item.files[0].preview)}
          <p>...waiting</p>
        {:then processedImage}
          <img src={processedImage} alt="preview" />
        {/await}
      </div>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an error with the value returning from a callback function. The `newImageURI` will not be returned.

Await synchronous and getBase64Async from Jimp are helpful solutions:

```
newImageURI = await image.blur(20).getBase64Async(Jimp.AUTO);
return newImageURI;
```

And the function call in the body remains unchanged:

```
{#await processImage(item.files[0].preview)} 
<p>...waiting</p> 
{:then processedImage}
<img src={processedImage} alt="preview" /> 
{/await}
```

I got this run.